# Dynamic Objects Id for Control

Tags: c++, qt, tableview, qml

I have some questions about what can I do with dynamic objects qml. I have to create a "many logs viewer" so in a window I've to create many TableViews as logFiles does the user have. I know how to create them dynamically but after the creation I have to add a logFile info and refresh it everytime a the file its modificated, basically when a new record arrives. The important question is can I add an Id to every dynamic TableView to add information at each model. Maybe on each component I'll have to add a combo to select wich file I want to view. this is why I need an Id or something to know wich object I'm going to point. actually I have to resize and reorder the components depending of how many windows does the user want to see. Its there a way to solve it ??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot assign `id` property to dynamically created object. This property managed by QML engine and associate with object while parsing. So you have to use `objectName` to refer to dynamic object or store pointer to object, returned by `Component.createObject()`